# Polymer 1.0: How to style distributed nodes with @apply?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

We have a custom element that is making an AJAX call to fetch some html generated on the server side and then injected into its light dom via Polymer.dom(this).innerHTML.  The response coming from the server has another custom element in it that exposes a CSS property for theming purposes.  On the main page, we're setting the value for the property, but it doesn't appear to be working.  How do we get Polymer to style dynamically added light DOM elements that are distributed by another element.

index.html

```
<style is="custom-style">
  x-bar {
    --mixin-property: {
      background: red;
    };
  }
</style>
...
<body>
  <x-baz>
  </x-baz>
</body>
```

x-baz.html

```
<dom-module id="x-baz">
  <template>
    <x-foo></x-foo>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "x-baz"
  });
</script>
```

x-foo.html

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax auto url="..." last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "x-foo",
    properties: {
      response: {
        type: String,
        obeserver: 'responseChanged'
      }
    },
    responseChanged: function(newVal) 
      Polymer.dom(this).innerHTML = newVal;
    }
  });
</script>
```

x-bar.html

```
<dom-module id="x-bar">
  <style>
    .elementToStyle {
      @apply(--mixin-property);
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <div class="elementToStyle">
      ...
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
</script>
  Polymer({
    is: "x-bar"
  });
</script>
```

The iron-ajax call returns `<x-bar> ... </x-bar>`.

I would expect the div inside the x-bar that comes back from the AJAX response to have a red background, but it doesn't seem to be working.  What do we need to adjust to make this work correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a ":" in your selector: `.elementToStyle: {`. If you remove that, does it work? You also may be running into some of the limitations of the style shimmer. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-properties-shim---limitations-and-api-details

Comment: Good catch!  I went back and checked our actual code and the extra ":" wasn't present.  We've tried several combinations of Polymer.updateStyles() and this.updateStyles() with no success.

Comment: I just noticed that my simplified example wasn't exactly what we were trying to do. I've updated the question with a new x-baz element and made it the element specified in the index page.

Comment: Try it using css variables as described in the the "Styling local DOM" example: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api . Call updateStyles on the inserted dom element after it is inserted.